# Issue with list and keys in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Doing a course on React, and got confused with one of the problems that I have to solve. I have to finish up the code after `{list &&` and before `</ul>` in such a way that I map the `<li>` so that it shows each tip. I confused myself with setting up the map function and in setting up the key properly.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Tips.css';

function Tips() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('api').then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    }).then((res) => {
      setList(Object.values(res));  
    })
  }, []);
  const [list, setList] = useState();
  return (
    <div className="tips">
      <ul className="tips__list">
      {list &&  tips.map((item.tip) =>
         return (
          <li key={item.tip} className="tips__item">{item.tip}</li>
        );
      )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Tips;
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys Please always check the docs before posting here.

Comment: What is `tips`? Did you mean to do `list.map(....`? What is the issue? what is your question?

Comment: what is `tips` in `tips.map` function ?

Comment: looks like typo `list.map(item => ...)`

Comment: `Array#map` documentation with examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.map()` should be called in your **list** variable.

```
  return (
    <div className="tips">
      <ul className="tips__list">
        {list &&
          list.map((item) => 
            <li key={item.tip} className="tips__item">
              {item.tip}
            </li>
          )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped solved my problem. Got confused with the map function, which you helped clear up. Will accept your answer when the cool down allows me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it like this

```
<li key={item.key}>{item.tip}</li>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.